# Makefile: o que é, e qual a finalidade?

Tags: terminologia, makefile

Estou querendo parar de usar IDE, e um amigo me aconselhou utilizar um Makefile para meus programas, então:

- O que é Makefile?
- Qual é sua finalidade?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normalmente associado a um utilitário chamado [`Make`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)), ou eventualmente alguma variação dele. Ele é apenas um arquivo de configuração que instrui o que o `Make` deve fazer.

O `Make` é usado para automatizar o processo de construção de aplicações chamando o compilador, *linkeditor*, executando testes, e até mesmo fazendo o *deploy*, entre outras operações possíveis. Originalmente ele foi criado para C, mas pode ser usado com qualquer tipo de aplicação, ainda que é comum cada linguagem ter seu próprio utilitário para gerenciar isso.

O arquivo é um mapa do projeto/solução indicando todos arquivos que estão envolvidos e como eles devem ser compilados. Cada um pode ter um jeito específico de ser tratado. Ele pode conter onde está as partes do projeto e suas dependências o qual o `Make` fará a gerência.

É comum ter algumas operações condicionais dependendo do resultado de operações anteriores. Por exemplo uma compilação só ocorrerá se o arquivo fonte foi modificado. Ou o *linker* ser chamado se toda compilação funcionar, ou ainda chamar um outro utilitário se os testes falharem.

É praticamente um sistema de *script* com finalidade mais específica.

Para alcançar esse objetivo há um conjunto de regras chamadas diretivas.

Exemplo retirado da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile):

```
edit : main.o kbd.o command.o display.o 
    cc -o edit main.o kbd.o command.o display.o
     
main.o : main.c defs.h
    cc -c main.c
kbd.o : kbd.c defs.h command.h
    cc -c kbd.c
command.o : command.c defs.h command.h
    cc -c command.c
display.o : display.c defs.h
    cc -c display.c

clean :
     rm edit main.o kbd.o command.o display.o
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/make.make).

Não precisar parar de usar IDE para usá-lo, até porque provavelmente já usa, só quer usar melhor agora.