# Quando um programa C é compilado, ele incluí todas as dependências necessárias para o seu funcionamento?

Tags: c, c++, compilação, biblioteca

Quando compilo um programa em C, todas as dependências serão compiladas juntas? Se não, é possível compilá-las?

Por exemplo, se eu incluo determinada biblioteca em meu programa, quando for compilá-lo, as passarei para o compilador, correto? Depois de compilado o programa, ele funcionará sem eu ter instalado em minha máquina determinada biblioteca?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compilação é feita no que você manda fazer, se não mandar não compila. Na verdade nenhum compilador normal compila dependências, se ele o fizer ele não é só um compilador. Em geral existe um sistema de *build* que faz essa tarefa e em muitos casos precisa escrever *scripts* para indicar sobre as dependências. Pode ver mais sobre em [Makefile: o que é, e qual a finalidade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154102/101). C e C++ usa o [Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)).

> Por exemplo, se eu incluo determinada biblioteca em meu programa, quando for compilá-lo, as passarei para o compilador, correto?

De forma geral, sim.

> Mas, agora, depois de compilado o programa, ele funcionara sem eu ter instalado em minha máquina determinada biblioteca?

Depende. Se for algo que já está no sistema operacional não precisa. Se for algo que só serve para sua aplicação então, em geral, tem que mandar junto ou pré-instalar. Mas isso não vale se gerar um executável monolítico, veja mais em [Qual a diferença entre linkagem estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149372/101).

Também pode ser útil: [Qual a diferença de DLL e lib?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44269/101)

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente isso que precisava! :)