# Raiz quadrada de números com expoentes

Tags: c

Estou fazendo o programa abaixo no Repl.it:

Construa um algoritmo que, tendo como dados de entrada dois pontos quaisquer do plano, P(x1,y1)  e Q(x2,y2), calcule a distância entre eles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    
    float x1,x2,y1,y2,d;
    
    printf("Digite o valor de x1: ");
    scanf("%f", &x1);
    printf("Digite o valor de x2: ");
    scanf("%f", &x2);
    printf("Digite o valor de y1: ");
    scanf("%f", &y1);
    printf("Digite o valor de y2: ");
    scanf("%f", &y2);   
    
    d = sqrt(pow(x2-x1,2)+pow(y2-y1,2));
    
    printf("A distância é de: %.2f", d);
  
}
```

Esse código no Dev C++ roda tranquilamente, porém no site Repl.it não. Alguém sabe se nesse sistema online teria que fazer algo diferente?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Você precisa compilar o código manualmente, com a flag -lm, para que a biblioteca math seja linkada. E depois executar o código manualmente também. https://replit.com/talk/ask/gcc-compiler-options/10280

Answer (score 2):

Se der uma olhada no [manual da função `sqrt()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sqrt.3.html), exatamente no texto de sua sinopse:

> ##### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```c
> #include <math.h>
>
> double sqrt(double x); 
> float sqrtf(float x); 
> long double sqrtl(long double x);
> ```
>
> **Link with -lm.**

Há uma orientação para fazer a linkedição da função usando a flag `-lm`.
Nessa [resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033940/11379709), de autoria do usuário [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient), é explicado qual o motivo de em C usar a flag:

> As funções em `stdlib.h` e `stdio.h` têm implementações em `libc.so`
> (ou `libc.a` para ligação estática), que é vinculada ao seu executável
> por padrão (como se `-lc` fosse Especificadas). O GCC pode ser
> instruído a evitar este link automático com as opções `-nostdlib` ou
> `-nodefaultlibs`.
>
> As funções matemáticas em `math.h` têm implementações em `libm.so` (ou
> `libm.a` para ligações estáticas), e `libm` não está ligada por
> padrão. Existem razões históricas para esta divisão `libm`/`libc`,
> nenhuma delas muito convincente.

Então uma solução é modificar o [makefile](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154102/137387) da sua aplicação e instruir o compilador para fazer linkedição da função usando a flag `-lm`.

Seguem os passos:

1. Abra o projeto no Replit e clique para exibir o painel de arquivos:
   [image: Exibir o painel de arquivos]
2. Abra o menu de opções:
   [image: Abra o menu de opções]
3. Escolha a opção *Show hidden files*:
   [image: Opção show hidden files]
4. Selecione o arquivo `Makefile`:
   [image: Makefile]
5. Localize a linha onde são feitas as atribuições para variável [`CFLAGS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#Implicit-Variables):
   [image: Variável CFLAGS]
6. Adicione a flag `-lm` a variável `CFLAGS`:
   [image: Adicionando a flag -lm]
7. Retorne ao menu de opções no painel de arquivos e dessa vez escolha a opção *Hide hidden files*:
   [image: opção Hide hidden files]
8. Execute o aplicativo:
   [image: Execute o aplicativo]

<sup>Teste no [Replit](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Raiz#main.c)</sup>